# Golang, variable with type from string

Tags: go

Is it possible to create variable with type from string?

Example:
 I have two types:

```
type FirstType struct {
    ...
}

type SecondType struct {
    ...
}

// also I have a string variable
var1 := "Second"
```

I want to create variable with type -  `String value + "Type"`:

```
var variable = []var1+"Type" // slice of "SecondType"
```

Expected result is like in this case:

```
var variable = []SecondType
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This is not possible. Go does not provide functionality to create variables of types that are not known statically. The type of a variable is always known statically. Consider using interfaces instead.

Comment: Suppose you have an interface IEvent, and a lot of different implementations of it. You can serialize them into the same object with properties Type and Data, but how would you deserialize them without having a very long switch case operation?

Comment: @GioGio Try to avoid this sort of situation.  One solution is to have a `Deserialize()` method in the interface implemented by each implemention to deserialize the `IEvent` in according to its specific type.

Comment: I'm confused, do you mean a Deserialize() on the IEvent interface? How can it be called if we don't have an instance of IEvent yet? I might be missing some important detail

Comment: @GioGio Ah sorry, I misunderstood.  For deserialisation, you could use an array or hash map of decoding functions instead of a switch statement.