# How to dynamically call variable?

Tags: go

I have two variables:

```
somethingA := 123
somethingB := 456
```

This two variables are filled though the system and lets presume that you have third variable:

```
type := "A"
```

With third variable you want to call somethingA but not like following:

```
if type == "A" {
    return somethingA
}else{
    return somethingB
}
```

but something like:

```
return something{type}
```

Is something like this possible in go?

Thank you

Comment: Just a heads up: type is keyword in go. so you cant name your variable that way.

Comment: I'm not sure what your example is asking, something like these questions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566124/golang-variable-with-type-from-string, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210188/instance-new-type-golang, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030884/is-there-a-way-to-create-an-instance-of-a-struct-from-a-string, etc.

Comment: Please who has downvoted my question let explain here what is reason for that.

Comment: @JimB - for exampel you have to arrays and sou want to go over for loop but one of them. Over my upper way you can only write two loops which is really not nice. It would be nice to pass array name if that is possible and then do loop.

Answer (score 4):

use a map

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
        x:=make(map[string]int)
        x["SomethingA"]=123
        x["SomethingB"]=456
    fmt.Println(x["SomethingA"])
    fmt.Println(x["SomethingB"])
}
```

Comment: absolutely if is possible, but if not?

Comment: no matter what I agree with you that this would be only proper way

Answer (score 2):

> Is something like this possible in go?

No.

All ways to do something like this boils down to the solution you showed.

Comment: Except using a map, which doesn't require any conditionals.

Comment: @Adrian The map just _hides_ the conditionals.

Comment: Not exactly. While there are certainly branches involved in the implementation of maps, it is not the same implementation at all. It is a completely different implementation based on a hash table.